Large jumps in joint space using OMPL Planners
I tried performing small movements of the endeffector (5cm in x and z direction) on a 6 DOF robotic arm.
The problem is, that using the OMPL Planners in MoveIt result in either a big jump in joint space (360 deg rotation around the base or the wrist and other unnecessary movements) or no solution being found.
The Planners i tried included:

RRT*, RRT and its variations
PRM*, PRM and its variations
others that mostly resulted in no solution being found

I have also tried constraining the movement by placing walls around the robot but that still resulted in big jumps in joint space.
Does anyone know what the issue might be?
Thanks in advance.
